# Do not resize width of a sticky div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky div which stays on top if I scroll past it. But it resize to the full screen size and I want it to keep the same size.

Here is CSS-code for the wrapper and the sticky class:

```
.wrapper{
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
background-color:#fff;
border-top: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
 }

.sticky {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 100;
border-top: 0;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #B8B8B8;
}
```

And here is the JS code:

```
var global = {}; 

$(document).ready(function(){

var element = $(".wrapper");
    offset = element.offset();

global.top = offset.top;
global.height = element.outerHeight();

});

$(window).scroll(function () {

var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();

if (scroll_top > global.top ) {
    $('.wrapper').addClass('sticky');
    $("body").css({
        "padding-top": global.height
    });

} else {

    $('.wrapper').removeClass('sticky');
    $("body").css({
        "padding-top": 0
    });
}

});
```

I created also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44ep8dz4/1/

Comment: by setting the position to fixed, you are removing it from the flow of the page and 100% in a container is not the same as 100% of the page. So if you want it to remain the same size, you need to give it a fixed width (px), which you can do in CSS or via JS.

Comment: but i have a responsive design in my mind, so I would have to work with breakpoints?

Comment: If you are thinking responsive @Felix I would avoid fixing anything on smaller displays as it is unreliable and can cause problems with zoom on mobile devices.

Comment: but i need it fixed, it is some kind of a game width a fixed element on top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `inherit`:

```
.sticky {
    width: inherit;
    ...
}
```

For the small screen problem, add this:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .sticky {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This overrides the `width: inherit` if the screen size is smaller than 768px.

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/wo9779sy/).

Comment: Genius! I didn't think this would work. Do you know if this will work in all relevant browsers?

Comment: I have just tested this is latest versions of IE, Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera. All work as expected :-)

Comment: I think IE6 & 7 doesn't support it. It should work in modern browsers.

Comment: it works, but I have a strange offset on the right side, you can see it here: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/budget/budget.html

Comment: that will be a padding/margin problem try adding this `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: doesnt change anything, where should I add it? to the sticky class?

Comment: Sorry @Felix you are already using that... The problem is that you have a padding on your `.container` which is making the `.wrapper` smaller when it is in the flow, once you fix it, it no longer has that padding and so it appears to be wider. Try removing your padding from `.container` and you will be able to see.

Comment: thanks, I removed it. One last problem: On a small screen size the sticky divs collapses to the smallest size, what can I do?

Comment: on small sizes it shrinks to have of the size, I cant use it like that!

Comment: I added a fix to my answer.

Comment: you are my hero! Thanks a lot!